# Image overlap with alphachannel doesn't work on QT

Tags: c++, qt

I've put two label of the same dimension overlapped on my GUI. On the first, that is on the back there is one image set by the pixmap of the label. The second label has another image set by pixmap that is trasparent in some pixel. During design i can see the back image via the front image. When I execute the program, the trasparent pixel of the second image are transformed into white pixel, so i cant see the back image. I'm using QT 5.10. The image are in .png format.

Comment: Can you please post a complete example? Can't reproduce the issue here (Qt 5.10 - Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved putting autoFillBackground on and i've changed the color of window in palette putting a transparent color